# WordPress : The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a WordPress project with two languages in the public folder. 
I have two folders. 
First folder is "ar"
at this link: 
http://www.gilenmobilya.com/ar/

And the second folder is "tr":
http://www.gilenmobilya.com/tr

Now when i open a post, for example this one:
http://www.gilenmobilya.com/tr/2017/03/21/ozel-siparisler/

I get this message:

> Not Found The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked wordpress permalink setting ?